# Efficient algorithm for package dependencies

Tags: algorithm, dependencies, breadth-first-search

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm for the following task:

**Input**:

1) Collection of packages where each package has unique Id and list of dependencies (each dependency is identified by Id as well).

2) Installation rules where each rule should be met.

The default rules include the following:

- Package can be installed iff all its dependencies are present in the input collection
- Package may not depend on itself, either directly or indirectly
- Circular dependencies are not allowed, either directly or indirectly

**Output**:

Correct order of package installation

I guess it's BFS + something. I need help with the "something" part. Thanks!

Comment: I believe they are no good solutions. See Stefano Zacchiroli's HdR dissertation [*Large-scale Modeling, Analysis, and Preservation of Free and Open Source Software*](https://upsilon.cc/~zack/research/publications/#index9h1) and some of his other publications

Comment: Does it help if you represent your problem as a graph problem? I can model it as DAG, and it seems simple, so I must be missing something or the question is incomplete.

Comment: read about topological sort